# Updating TextBoxFor when changing DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dropdownlistfor

I'm using ASP MVC 3 and currently having a problem getting new data in my textboxes when I change the value of my dropdownlistfor.

```
<div id="BagelProductEdit">
            <h2>Bagel</h2>
             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionBagel, Model.LstBagelsList, new { @class = "width200", @onchange = "refreshTextBoxFors()" })   
             <br /> 

               <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bagelnaam</td><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LstBagels.ElementAt(x.SelectedOptionBagel).Name,new { Name ="txtEditBagelName" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vertaling</td><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LstBagels.ElementAt(x.SelectedOptionBagel).NameFr,new { Name ="txtEditBagelNameFr" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prijs</td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LstBagels.ElementAt(x.SelectedOptionBagel).Price,new { Name ="txtEditBagelPrice" })</td>
                </tr>   

            </table>
             <input class="button widthorderProduct" type="submit" name="BtnEditBagel" value="Edit een bagel" />
        </div>
```

How can I get the refreshed value in my textboxes when the value of my dropdownlist changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID to that dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionBagel, Model.LstBagelsList, new { @class = "width200", @onchange = "refreshTextBoxFors()", id= "myDDL" })
```

Then, in the `refreshTextBoxFors()` you can access the dropdownlist selected value this way (assuming you are using **jQuery**):

```
$("#myDDL").val();
```

If you need the selected text (not the value):

```
$("#myDDL :selected").text();
```

In you are not using jQuery, but plain **Javascript**, you can use this for getting the selected value in a DropDownList:

```
var e = document.getElementById("myDDL");
var selValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

**EDIT - To set the data of textboxes:**

Once you have the DDL selected value you can do:

```
if(selValue == '1'){
   $('#test').val('here is the value you want to put');
}
else{
$('#test').val('other value');
}
```

Now, in the example in your comment, it seems you have a list of TextBoxFors. So if you put an id in a loop, it will set that to all of your textboxes. You can put a `@class = "test"` instead and access the textboxes using `$('.test')` instead of `$('#test')`.

Comment: This is a good example how to retrieve index but still the textboxfors are not updating..

I now have a function to retreive the index from the dropdownlist:
    function refreshTextBoxFors() {
            
            $("#bagelname").val($("#myDDL").val());

            index = $("#bagelname").val();

        }

And this is my textboxfor:
    <td>Bagelnaam</td><td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LstBagels.ElementAt(index).Name,new { Name ="txtEditBagelName" , id="test"})</td>